# How I can restrict other persons to login on my app?

Tags: android

I am new, I have a problem with my android application, it has a login system connected with mysql and php to access, but when I misspell the password / user it still lets me in, and I have already checked it several times without giving the possible mistake

```
    private void validarUsuario(String URL){
    StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(!response.isEmpty()) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PrincipalActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }




     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            user=edtUsuario.getText().toString();
            pass=edtPassword.getText().toString();
            if (!user.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty()){
                validarUsuario("http://192.168.1.69/taller/validar_usuario.php");
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Debes llenar los campos vacíos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: please post your code where you have called validarUsuario method

Comment: Done, I hope you can help me

Comment: I think you should check your php code for comparing user added email and password to your existing database.

Comment: Can you believe me when I say that I have been checking it for 2 hours both the code and the database, but no matter how much I have done it and redone I cannot find the error

Comment: It looks like your response is not empty even if the validation isn't successful.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments you should add some condition like I have added in below code after first if condition..

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            user=edtUsuario.getText().toString();
            pass=edtPassword.getText().toString();
            if (!user.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty()){
                if(user.equals('userName') && pass.equals('password')){
                validarUsuario("http://192.168.1.69/taller/validar_usuario.php");
}
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Debes llenar los campos vacíos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: In validar_usuario is this condition
                    if(!response.isEmpty()){
                        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Segundo.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Usuario, contraseña incorrectas",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

Comment: I don't get it what are you telling about?

Comment: I understand that in public void onResponse (String response) there is a Boolean response to the database check, if the data is found it returns 1 to advance to the next activity, otherwise it will return 0 and take the else to show the text invalid user

Comment: You should add authentication code in php file or java file so I wrote an answer in java file so response return boolean value then It should be check before response comes right?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, apparently I had misstated one of the variables in the php, which is rare, since I was checking it many times and had not seen it, an apology, and thanks to those who took the time to read / reply my question

Comment: Yes I was also talking about this in my comments but you told me that you have checked many times so that's why I wrote answer for you